# Free up memory returned by functions

Tags: c, free

Should I free up memory returned by the following two functions in the caller function? I see that it is ok with function `get_current_time` but not ok with the `get_filename_ext`. I see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911517/freeing-memory-returned-from-c-functions), but not sure that answers my question. In general what should I look for?

```
char *get_current_time(void){
    struct tm *local;
    time_t t;
    t = time(NULL);
    local = gmtime(&t);
    return asctime(local);
}

char *get_filename_ext(const char *filename) {
        const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
        if(!dot || dot == filename) return "";
        return dot + 1;
    }
```

Comment: In general, other than `strdup` (that is a POSIX function) there aren't many ANSI C functions that need free (other than `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` clearly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these functions allocate any memory. So there's actually nothing to free.

The `char*` returned by `asctime` is an internal buffer. So you can't free it anyway.

Comment: The second one returns the dot pointer that's been allocated on the stack, so technically it does.

Comment: @Mystical :But that I would not know unless I look at the function implementation.

Comment: @Marc B: The `dot` pointer points to somewhere inside `filename`.

Comment: @Lamia: You'll have to look at the function anyway (or documentation) to see whether you need to free the returned pointer. There's no other way to tell. Generally speaking, returning pointers that need to be freed is not good practice.

Comment: @Mystical: Since char* returned b asctime is an internal buffer if I have to assign that value to a member variable in a structure do I have to use strdup()? Other wise its value going to change if the function is called second time.

Comment: Correct, you will need to copy the string in some way. `strdup` is one way to do it.